# Do you get anything for beating a Bonus Round?

Tags: mcpixel

After beating 3 scenes in a row I was given a bonus round.  By sheer luck I won.  Do you get anything special for beating a bonus round?  I haven't seen anything pop up or anything.

If it matters, the bonus round had a bunch of me standing around and one lying on the floor.  It was during the Baby section (Chapter 1) 3rd door (Desert).

Answer (score 2):

Getting all three white squares and beating the bonus round serves no purpose that I am aware of. However, if you get gold squares, you will unlock Extras in the Extras menu.